# Maven how to add Git repos as dependency

Tags: java, git, maven, github, maven-3

I have been struggling to add the Git project as the dependency in my maven project. I have the Git as the SSO based repository where it returns me the 
https repo path as https://username@git.server.name/scm/pathToRepo
 I tried adding repositories tag in my pom.xml but I am getting PKIX path building failed error I even tried adding the server.cer to the cacerts of my Java.
I also tried passing username:password to the github repo path.

My intention here is to avoid the way to manually download the project using git command and converting it to jar and want pom.xml to take care of the cloning the project from the Git repo path , compiling and adding it as a dependency.

Comment: I have already tried with the link mentioned before posting the question, and it doesn't work for me 
```<scm>
 <connection>scm:git:https://username@git.source.xyz.com/scm/projectpath.git</connection>
  <url>scm:git:git@git.source.xyz.com/scm/projectpath.git</url>
 <developerConnection>scm:git:git@git.source.xyz.com/scm/projectpath.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>SomeId</id>
 <url>https://username@git.source.xyz.com/scm/projectpath.git</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>```
the moment i add dependency I get Failed to read artifact descriptor

Comment: In Maven you can add dependencies from a repository but not from a git repository directly. There are options to add dependencies if those git repos exist on jitpack ...

Comment: can you share some example or url so that I can refer that to achieve through JitPack actually I want my maven to take care of the downloading the projects from the Git and add it as the dependency so that I can use it on multiple projects instead of me downloading the project manually there are benefits as well with this approach I hope if there are ways to achieve it